# Вывести одно слово из списка при помощи цикла

Tags: python, list, циклы

Всем привет, нужна помощь, нужно вывести одно слово из списка, при помощи цикла for, к примеру список ['дерево','лопата','камень']

Comment: Уточните задачу. Какое именно слово нужно вывести. То есть к примеру, вы вводите слово при помощи функции input() и производите поиск по списку, если я правильно понимаю

Comment: `for i in ['derevo', 'lopata', 'kamen'][:1]: print(i)`

Comment: К примеру мне нужно вывести последнее слово из списка, у нас это 'камень', и нужно чтобы оно одно вывелось

Comment: "Вывести одно слово" (какое?) и "вывести последнее слово" это разные задачи. О чем именно речь?

Comment: Хорошо, вывести любой слово из списка, но чтоб оно было одно

Comment: print(lst[0]) - выведет одно слово из списка.

Answer (score 1):

Можно цикл обернуть в генератор и использовать `next()`:

```
list_ = ['дерево','лопата','камень']
gen = (i for i in list_)
print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень легко.

```py
a = ["1","2","3"]
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i])
```

Или же

```py
a = ["1","2","3"]
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Ему нужно было одно слово, ты не до конца понял условие :D

Comment: Аааааааааааааааа